# Some strings and integers of the elements of an ArrayList<Object> needs to be shown in a ListView. How should one implement it?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

I'm not even sure if using a ListView is the best solution or not.

I'll have a JSON file that has the neccessary info about customers and I'll need to display the names of the customers in a scrollable list where users can pick one by tapping on it and then a new activity would start.

I know how to parse JSON files and I coded the neccessary classes such as Customer, ExistingCustomer, Order, PaymentType (enum) etc.

In the end I'll have an ArrayList consisting of Customer instances where each and I'll be getting their member fields' values this way:

```
 customersToView[i].setCompanyName(ArrayList.get(i).getCompanyName);
 customersToView[i].setPhoneNumber(ArrayList.get(i).getPhoneNo);
```

etc. So which View class should I use? A ViewList I assumed, but I'm not sure. I'm not sure about how the list adapter should be coded either. Can you help me out?

Comment: `an ArrayList consisting of HashMaps` no, you'll have a `List<Customer>`

Comment: Since you have `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>` why did't you use `SimpleAdapter` ? There is no neeed to create model ... it would be just waste of CPU cycles and memory

Comment: Heard it was easier to use ArrayList<HashMap> when putting its data onto a listview. Using a ArrayList<Customer> would make a lot more sense though, yeah. Edited the question.

Comment: If ListView should be the best solution for implementing dynamic view of list, it is not. You should check out RecyclerView, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html